# Wildcard in condition MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there any way of doing something like this:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column_two = *
```

I want to use some graphs that I use for checking specific data in order to check ALL data. And it would be nice not to have to write new queries specifically for that.

In other words nullify the where condition with a wildcard.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired output? I'm having trouble figuring out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, I basically want to get the same output that I would get from 
"SELECT column FROM table"